How to Achieve Continuous Printing of Long Receipts on Dot Matrix Printer?
I am developing a printing service based on Golang. We need to be able to print long HTML files continuously.
I have an Epson LK-82 dot matrix printer and need to print long receipts. Currently, we convert HTML to PDF for printing, but we encounter the following issues:
Here is what we expect

Here are the effects we can achieve ourselves
The printed content gets interrupted at page breaks, resulting in outputs like this:

We tried splitting the PDF using Mutool, but there were still blank lines at page breaks when printing.
When attempting to print a single long PDF page, the printer seems unable to recognize the super long page and only prints part of the content or the first page (all in A4 width and height).
We tried the following printing methods, but none solved the problem:
List item

SumatraPDF
PDFtoPrinter
Ghostscript

The commands I have tried
gswin32 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -sOutputFile="%printer%EPSON LQ-82KF ESC/P2"  out.pdf

Question:
Is there a solution to achieve either of the following goals?

Avoid blank lines when printing with pagination.
Successfully print super long pages.

Possible causes we suspect:

The printer itself does not support super long pages.
Issues with the PDF conversion tool.
Issues with the PDF printing tool.
Incorrect printing method.

Additional Information:
Operating System:

Windows

For reference, a similar question has been asked on GitHub: https://github.com/sumatrapdfreader/sumatrapdf/issues/4736
demo pdf on this link
Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem?

Two ideas spring to mind: generate your output as multi-page PDF, at the size of the paper you're using(probably Letter, 8.5" x 11"). Don't create a single, very long page. That should allow your printer driver to handle the page breaks properly. Or, output the data direct to the printer, using ESC/P2 to print lines and other formatting. You'll need to create your own template code to handle page lengths, etc. This was how it was done when I last used a DM printer (c.1995), before PDF was an open standard. I couldn't find a reference to that printer, so things may have changed in thirty years.

There's no command supplied for Ghostscript, so it's impossible to investigate the problem from that point of view. There's no code supplied so this isn't a coding question and is almost certainly off-topic for stack overflow.

@KenS I had suggested GS as the most likely candidate for long prints (but had not supplied a command) since AFAIK GSPDL can printout longer than an mswimpr2 page driver (2m or more?) however the OP has not grasped that point that an esc/p2 direct output would be needed to not introduce page margins at natural page driven driver output. @ Tangentially Perpendicular is correct the esc/p2 coded table should be directly sent port to port without any windows interference. @ ZhangZuoliang the old command manual should be here https://files.support.epson.com/pdf/general/escp2ref.pdf

OK so you are using the mswinpr2 device. That means Ghostscript isn't doing any page splitting. That device simply renders the content to a bitmap, and then sends it to the Windows print system. So your problem is that the Windows print system doesn't understand infinite length media for that printer. There is an Epson device available for Ghostscript, in fact there are at least 2; epson and epsonc. eps9mid and eps9high are special modes for dot matrix printers. God knows if 'epson' still works after all these years, but you can try it, it's intended for dot matrix Epson printers.

FWIW the epson device produces output that looks plausible, just reading the binary, but there's no way to tell without a printer which accepts ESC/P, and I no longer have one.
